# Use six 6s in an expression that equals 1,000

Tags: calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

> **Given:**  six 6s
>   **Goal:** Construct an expression with value $1,000$

---

Rules:

- Use all six digits in each expression.
- No other digits are allowed.
- Concatenation of digits is allowed.
- One horizontal fraction bar is required.
- No grouping symbols are allowed.
- At most two subtraction signs are allowed.
- At most two decimal points are allowed. 
  (They are for regular use of the decimal point here,
  and not for repeated decimals.)

Other than the fraction bar for division, any subtraction signs used, and the role of the decimal point(s), no other arithmetic or any other different operations/functions//symbols are allowed, except as previously mentioned.

Comment: All of these answers fall into a pattern, so if you get one or more, it is possible that they may help you to get other answers in the set of answers.

Comment: How many answers are you expecting?

Comment: @question_asker - I am expecting six answers, not including any variations that result by multiplying the numerator and the denominator by -1.

Answer (score 8):

Answer #1 is

> $\frac{666 - 66}{.6}  = 1000$   $~~~~$and the variation$~~~~$ 
>  $\frac{66 - 666}{-.6} = 1000$

Answer #2 is:

> $\frac{666 - 6}{.66}  = 1000$   $~~~~$and the variation$~~~~$ 
>  $\frac{6 - 666}{-.66} = 1000$

Answer #3 is:

> $\frac{66 - 6}{.66-.6} = 1000$  $~~~~$and the variation$~~~~$ 
>  $\frac{6 - 66}{.6-.66} = 1000$

Answer #4 (due to Narmer) is:

> $\frac{ 6}{.666-.66} = 1000$  $~~~~$and the variation$~~~~$ 
>  $\frac{-6}{.66-.666} = 1000$

Comment: Helping out here $\cfrac{6}{.666-.66}$ = 1000

Comment: @ Narmer - Why don't you post it as a separate solution to get credit for it with arrows up for it!?

Comment: @OliveStemforn Nah, just having a little bit of fun, upvotes are not needed for it ;)

Comment: What about $\cfrac{6}{.6}\cdot\cfrac{66}{.66}$ = 1000?

Comment: @Narmer And from that  $\cfrac{666}{.666}  = 1000$

Comment: @ Narmer - 1) It violates the one fraction bar rule.  2) It violates that it uses multiplication, which is an operation that is not allowed.

Comment: @Lacklub That's what question_asker already posted, it is one of the 6 answers for sure

Comment: @OliveStemforn Oh, didn't understand that the fraction bar should be only one... The multiplication could be transformed in a fraction (just like Paul Evans answer)... So one to go still! :)

Comment: @Narmer Sorry. Did you get  $\cfrac{-66}{.6 - .666} = 1000$ ?

Comment: @Lacklub DING DING DING! Gratz, I think you got the last one: $\cfrac{66}{.666-.6}  = 1000$

Comment: @Lacklub - That is the last one, but it's the variation of the basic one.

Comment: @ Narmer - Your post was after Lacklub's.  You have the basic form of the last one.

Comment: Just food for thought: Answer 1 and 4 look like reciprocals, if the decimals have to be on the bottom. Answer 3 is it's own "reciprocal". The answer I posted is the "reciprocal" of answer 2.

Answer (score 4):

I'll have a go at it

> $\cfrac{666 - 66}{.6}$

Comment: Good.  Yes, this is one of them so far.

Comment: * * * * At this moment, other than Narmer's solution, which was not posted as a public solution, as well as all variations (with their changes in signs), there is one more basic one I'm looking for.  But I'm going on a break away from here for an hour, give or take. * * * *

Answer (score 4):

Here's another <s>one</s>two

> $\frac{666-6}{.66}$ or $\frac{666}{.666}$

Comment: The first one was covered by JoeMalpass (first).  Your second one is new. (edit)

Comment: According to the number of minutes ago on my screen, JoeMalpass posted it 2 minutes before you did.

Comment: I see I am wrong.

Comment: @olive no problem! I'm not super concerned with being first, tbh

Comment: @ question_asker- I'm concerned that I don't know how to read "answered ago" and when last edited.

Comment: How did you make the more compact (smaller font) fractions? I like that, it's neater.

Comment: @JoeMalpass Click 'edit' under the answer to have a look.

Comment: @Lawrence I tried that, but I can't see any difference between the two different sizes as they appear in the plain text editor window.

Comment: @JoeMalpass Mine is \$ \frac { numerator } { denominator } \$ without spaces, whereas yours uses \cfrac

Comment: @JoeMalpass Which is the *larger* font you're comparing this with?

Comment: @Lawrence I think he was talking about the result of using cfrac vs just frac (which, incidentally, was what I used purely because I didn't know about cfrac)

Comment: @question_asker & Lawrence, that was it - the cfrac Vs. frac. That's what I get for copy/paste/editing instead of learning the syntax from scratch, hahaha.

Comment: @JoeMalpass Seems like we're on different ends of the same boat, haha

Answer (score 1):

I've got:

> $$\frac{666 - 66}{.6} $$

And I think a new one:

> $$\frac{\frac{6}{.6}}{\frac{.6}{66-6}}$$

Comment: Dennis posted this an hour ago. But congrats on getting a correct answer

Comment: @Bishop yeah, just saw that so added a new one

Comment: I think this is disallowed by the rules (which sucks, because I like it)

Comment: @ Paul Evans - It violates the rules ( it uses two horizontal fraction bars instead of the required one), but I like the creativity.

Comment: * * *  All of the answers have been posted in some form or another. * * *